# Data is being sent to my database without making a request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, postgresql

I'm sending data in ReactJS to my PostgreSQL database as well as images to my server using NodeJS. It works when sending data in my POST requests in React but for some reason after that, data is still being added even if I don't send any data on my front-end.

**ReactJS(onClicks)**

`file: event.target.files[0]`

```
onClickHandler = () => {
    const data = new FormData()
    data.append('file', this.state.file)
    axios.post("http://localhost:3000/albums", data, { 
  })


async save2(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

 await this.setState(prevState => ({
  files: prevState.files.map((file, index) => ({...file, index})
)}));
  let files = this.state.files;

await this.setState(prevState => ({
   albums: {...prevState.albums, files}
}))

    let albums = this.state.albums;

    let albumRequest = new Request(`http://localhost:3000/albums/`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
    body: JSON.stringify(albums),
    });


    fetch(albumRequest)
      .then((response) =>
        response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
          })



}

onClick(event) {
  this.onClickHandler();
  this.save2(event);
}
 


render() {
  return (

    <ButtonToggle onClick={this.onClick} color="success">Save
           </ButtonToggle> 

)
}
```

**NodeJS**

```
    

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: (req, file, cb) => {
                cb(null, 'public')
            }, 
            filename: (req, file, cb) => {
                cb(null, Date.now() + '-' +file.originalname)
            }
        })
        var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

        app.post('/albums', upload.single('file'), apiCall.addData);
```

**NodeJS**

```
 const addData = (request, response) => {
    const uuid = uuidv4(); 
    let album_id;

    var query1 = db.pool.query('INSERT INTO albums (title, date, description, id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *' , [request.body.title, request.body.date, request.body.description, uuid])
        .then(res => {
          album_id = res.rows[0].id;
          console.log('INSERT ' + res.rowCount);
        }).then(() => {
           const dbQueryPromises = [];
           for (let i = 0; i < request.body.files.length; i++) {
            dbQueryPromises.push(db.pool.query('INSERT INTO songs (id, name, link, index, album_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ON CONFLICT (album_id, index) DO NOTHING RETURNING *', [uuidv4(), request.body.files[i].name, request.body.files[i].link, request.body.files[i].index, album_id]))
          }
            return Promise.all(dbQueryPromises);
            }).then(res => {
             console.log('Array of INSERT result for second insert: ');
        }).then(() => {
           var query = db.pool.query(
            'INSERT INTO file (name, type, size, path, album_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ON CONFLICT (album_id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *',
            [request.file.filename, request.file.mimetype, request.file.size, request.file.path, album_id]);
          }).then((res) => {
             console.log("INSERT INTO file(images) " + request.body.data);
          })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));


    }
```

I see code with connecting to and ending the database connection. I'm wondering if anything like that will apply here.

Comment: can you share where did you call `save2` and `onClickHandler `

Comment: Okay I did. In an onClick for a save button..

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to change this code

```
<ButtonToggle onClick={this.onClick} color="success">Save
       </ButtonToggle>
```

to this

```
<ButtonToggle onClick={()=>this.onClick()} color="success">Save
       </ButtonToggle>
```

Comment: I made it work like this `onClick={(e)=>this.onClick(e)}` but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Please check your document format indentations and syntax, 
strong text and use arrow function in react onClick handler

> https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-torvalds-lpbxr